# Quickest way to sort multiple lists together, each list with a billion entries

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have 4 lists of a ~billion entries each and am trying to sort all 4 lists according to the sort order in list1.

I've tried

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)))
```

and

```
sorted_index = np.argsort(list1)
list1 = [list1[i] for i in sorted_index]
list2 = [list2[i] for i in sorted_index]
list3 = [list3[i] for i in sorted_index]
list4 = [list4[i] for i in sorted_index]
```

and the second method is faster than the first, but it is still very time consuming.  Is there a more efficient way to do this sorting? Simply zipping them together and sorting is not an option because I need the lists unzipped at the end.

Can this be done with mapping and adding a custom get function as C.B. suggested in the comments?

Comment: Is this using numpy?

Comment: The first method isn't, but the second method is.

Comment: What if I told you there's no quick way to do anything to **four billion** items?

Comment: Well, in my experience Python is quite efficient in the functions like sorting and list copying. Sorting a billion rows will consume a lot of time. To get this code faster you probably need to use more CPUs of your computer on threads (not processes as you don't want to copy billion entries form process to process). And this is where the Python story gets weak. A better way is to use another language like Java 8 and its streams that have parallelSorting implemented. Sorry, that there's no better answer I can give.

Comment: Sorting is unecessary, just maintain a mapping of old index to new index. Then add a custom `get` function that uses the mapping.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: `Simply zipping them together and sorting is not an option because I need the lists unzipped at the end.` Isn't that what your first code example is doing already? The cost of the unzipping is likely trivial next to the sort cost.

Comment: Actually, no.  The cost of unzipping is much more.

Comment: Are the four lists already sorted, and why do you want to combine them, and still unzip then at the end?

Comment: No, the four lists aren't already sorted. Combining them and then sorting is a way to sort list2-4 based on the sort of list1, but in the end I want to unzip them and have 4 separate lists again.

Comment: What are the types of the list items? Perhaps a 4x1B numpy matrix is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_index = np.argsort(list1)
print list2[sorted_index]
print list3[sorted_index]
...
```

still might be a little slow ... but much better probably

this assumes your lists are actually numpy arrays...

Comment: i dont think they are, im pretty sure the lists themselves are just regular lists

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the entries in the list are.  A general sort will likely use qsort.  This means O(n log n) sort time.  For something like dictionary words this would be incredibly inefficient.  If the average length of sorted elements, let's say K, is significantly less than log n, then you'll get much faster results by populating a trie and reading it out.  It will also be much less space consuming than a merge sort.  The runtime of populating a trie is O(n K).  log n, when n is 4 billion, is quite large.

Comment: Python's `sorted` (and `list.sort`) don't use `qsort`, they use [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). It's still `O(n log n)` in the general case, being built on a customized hybrid of merge sort and insertion sort, but if the data contains runs of ordered (or reversed data), the runtime approaches `O(n)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, unless the list entries are completely random, they are likely very repetitive even if not sorted. Eg., words in a book contain quite a few repetitions, but they won't be in order. Log file entries, if they start with dates, will be sorted, but  their middle parts will be repetitive (same log statements). Sorting words in a book would be a perfect example of when to use a trie. A log file is a little trickier. There you would rather split the repetitive part of each line from the already-sorted parts and use a tuple whose entries would come from two independent sorted lists.